# Не доступен protected член из подкласса в другом пакете

Tags: java

Почему возникает ошибка в закомментированной строчке, ведь protected челны класса, доступны классам, находящимся в том же пакете,и подклассам — в других пакетах.

```
package one;
public class One {
    protected int val;
}
```

Если такой же класс создать в пакете `package one`, то в закомментированной строке ошибки уже не будет. Для `static` переменной в обоих случаях ошибки не будет.

```
package two;
import one.One;
public class Two extends One{
    private One o = new One();
    //private int val = o.val;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В дополнение к [этому правильному ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554949/10105), несколько слов о мотивации.

Если бы производный класс имел бы доступ к `protected`-полям *любого* объекта базового типа, то было бы очень легко обойти инкапсуляцию. Действительно, пусть у вас есть объект типа `A`, и `protected`-поле `x`. Тогда вы из *любой* точки кода смогли бы получить доступ к `x`, используя такой простой трюк:

```
class FakeA extends A {
    public void SetXFor(A obj, int x) {
        obj.x = x;
    }
}

new FakeA().SetXFor(obj, 42);
```

Чтобы такие трюки были невозможны, доступ к `protected`-членам и ограничен текущим экземпляром объекта.

Comment: А разве не нарушает инкапсуляцию возможность доступа к полю из классов пакета?

Comment: С моей точки зрения — да, нарушает. Разработчики Java, судя по всему, считают, что пакет — набор тесно связанного кода, поэтому они разрешили это.

Answer (score 9):

На первый взгляд, ошибки в вашем коде не видно, но она есть.

Вы правы, `protected` свойства доступны для наследников в других пакетах. Но посмотрите, как вы обращаетесь из `Two` к родителю:

```
private One o = new One();
```

Вы не используете здесь родственные связи. Вы просто создали новый экземпляр класса, никак не связанный с вашим. Если вы хотите обратиться к **родительскому** классу, следует использовать ключевое слово `super`:

```
private int val = super.val;
```